# PHP sort array by several criteria

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am coding with PHP and having a multidimensional array. I would like to sort my array. The most important criteria is total points. The second criteria is name.

In other words, the array should be sorted that way:

1st by [info][total], descending

2nd by [info][name], ascending

```
Array (
  [183] => Array (
    [3] => Array (
      [1] => Array ()
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [8] => Array ()
    )

    [info] => Array (
      [name] => Doe John /* 2nd criteria */
      [total] => 4800 /* 1st criteria */
    )
  )

  [380] => Array (
    [4] => Array (
      [6] => Array ()
    )

    [info] => Array (
      [name] => Davis Ben /* 2nd criteria */
      [total] => 14500 /* 1st criteria */
    )

    [2] => Array (
      [5] => Array ()
    )
  )
)
```

So, the result should be like this:

```
Array (
  [380] => Array (
    [4] => Array (
      [6] => Array ()
    )

    [info] => Array (
      [name] => Davis Ben
      [total] => 14500
    )

    [2] => Array (
      [5] => Array ()
    )
  )

  [183] => Array (
    [3] => Array (
      [1] => Array ()
    )

    [1] => Array (
      [8] => Array ()
    )

    [info] => Array (
      [name] => Doe John
      [total] => 4800
    )
  )
)
```

I have tried this:

```
foreach ($array as &$item)
{
  uasort($item, function ($a, $b)
  {
    if ($a['total'] == $b['total']
    {
      return $b['name'] - $a['name'];
    }
    else
    {
      return $b['total'] - $a['total'];
    }
  }); 
}
```

I also tried this, but it does not help:

```
foreach ($array as &$item)
{
  uasort($item, function ($a, $b)
  {
    if ($a['info']['total'] == $b['info']['total'])
    {
      return $b['info']['name'] - $a['info']['name'];
    }
    else
    {
      return $b['info']['total'] - $a['info']['total'];
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: *"I am coding with PHP"* -- can you prove that? I can see only some output of `var_dump()` and an unspoken request for somebody to write code for you.

Comment: You seem to have a lot of empty arrays, why don't you filter them away? Then you can use `usort()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php with a callback function of your own which sorts by those criteria.

Comment: @axiac I have done that array with PHP and inserted data from MySQL database, but I just cannot sort the array. There are empty arrays, because this is just an example.

Comment: Sorting by complex or multiple criteria can be achieved using the [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) PHP function and its siblings.

Comment: @axiac I added my PHP code to the opening post.

Comment: From the desired output I understand you want to sort the big array, not its elements. The code you tried says something else. Pass the big array to `usort()`. It will call your custom comparison function with two items from the big array. Analyze the data they contain (`$a['info']['$total]`, `$a['info']['name']`, `$b...`) and return the correct order.

Comment: @axiac I updated to openin post after trying another way, but it does not work. I do not want to destroy index values when sorting the array.

Comment: Indeed, [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) is not the function to use here. Have you tried another one?

Comment: @axiac Yes, I have tried usort, uasort, uksort, etc. but I do not know which one to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request of your question (order the values by custom criteria, keep the associations between keys and values) perfectly matches the description of PHP function [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php).

The code is something like this:

```
$input = Array(
    '183' => Array(
        '3' => Array(
            '1' => Array(),
        ),
        '1' => Array(
            '8' => Array(),
        ),
        'info' => Array(
            'name'  => 'Doe John',      /* 2nd criteria */
            'total' => 4800,            /* 1st criteria */
        ),
    ),
    '380' => Array(
        '4' => Array(
            '6' => Array(),
        ),
        'info' => Array(
            'name'  => 'Davis Ben',     /* 2nd criteria */
            'total' => 14500,           /* 1st criteria */
        ),
        '2' => Array(
            '5' => Array(),
        ),
    ),
);

uasort($input, function (array $a, array $b) {
    // compare using the 1st criterion
    if ($a['info']['total'] != $b['info']['total']) {
        return $b['info']['total'] - $a['info']['total'];       // < 0 when $a > $b (descending)
    }

    // equality on the 1st criterion, use the 2nd one
    return strcmp($a['info']['name'], $b['info']['name']);      // < 0 when $a < $b (ascending)
});
```

Comment: Yes, thanks axiac. I just noticed that I was using foreach without any reason. I took it away. Now the code looks just like yours :)